# How to display a table in twitter bootstrap (even if its empty)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In twitter bootstrap (and/or css), how can we ensure a table is displayed in its full form (with fixed dimensions), no matter whether or not its row are populated with data or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to completely understand the question. But if you want to check if your table is fully displayed, I will use JavaScript/jQuery.

You could just check if the table has the size that you put in the CSS but I don't think that what you mean with your question:

```
if($(".table").height()==??) {
  //DO WHAT YOU WANT
}
```

If your data are put on one line in the table, you can then check the number of row and multiply by the size of one row: https://jsfiddle.net/ugppwzsc/1/

But if your row have various size, you will have to calculate the size of every row and check if it's what you want:

```
var cal = 0;
$( "tr" ).each(function() {
  cal += $(this).height();
});
if($("table").height()==cal) {
  //DO WHAT YOU WANT
}
```